# Run exe from java on Linux

Tags: java

I am not sure if this is possible, I wanted to run a Windows exe application from the command line from my java program - something like

```
Process process = Runtime.getRunTime().exec("myapp.exe --params");
```

The catch is that I would like to run the java application which calls the exe from within an OS X or Linux environment.

I was wondering if anyone has done this or has any suggestions on how it could be done?  Thanks

Edit:  thanks for responding.  I did want to add that I would probably not want to use wine to run the exe and would probably want to create some type of wrapper around the exe file to call functions from the dll directly from java.  I haven't done this before and was wondering if any pointers on this.

Comment: I don't think the code as it is will work. You can try to have Java start [Wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/Main_Page) which in turn will start the .exe.

Comment: try calling wine application passing myapp.exe as parameter to wine

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a very good design choice. To be able to run windows exe's in Linux you need to have at the least Wine installed. Your application would then be dependent upon the availability of some other 3rd party application that your users may or maynot have access to.

Answer (score 8):

`exe` files are have a specific, Windows-only format called [Portable Executable (PE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). It's not compatible with the format Linux uses for executable files, not to mention differences in system calls between the two systems.

You can't just run an `exe` file on Linux, regardless of whether it's being run from Java.

If you really need it to work, you have two options:

- Use a Windows compatability layer for Linux in the form of [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/) (or similar tools)
- Recompile your exe for Linux